# Problemas para mostrar una fecha capturada con datapicker en una smartgrid

Tags: angular5, datepicker, formato

Soy nuevo en `angular` y tengo el siguiente problema del formulario de facturas donde capturo por medio del componente `datapicker` 5 fechas diferentes para calcular los días que transcurren entra dos fechas, estoy pensando en usar para esa función `moments.js`.

Sin embargo, cuando cree una `smarthgrid` para mostrar todas las facturas, tengo el siguiente problema, las fechas me las muestre de la siguiente forma "**2017-01-17T00:00:00.000Z**" como puedo configurar en esa `smartgrid` para que solo aparezca "**2017-01-17**" ¿Cómo se puede mostrar de esa forma solo en el `smartgrid`?

Gracias por al ayuda.

Código del botón del `datapicker` en **factura.html**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="calendar-input form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="dpDate" ngbDatepicker #a="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="invoice.date"  (ngModelChange)="invoice.date = $event">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="a.toggle()" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es dar formato puedes intentar con los pipe de angular. `[(ngModel)]="invoice.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'"`. No es necesario hacer ningún import. Más info: https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-tips-formatting-dates-with-a-custom-date-pipe-dd-mm-yyyy/

Comment: Gracias @Angel voy a ver que tal me va